# How do I reorder the playlist items in the VLC playlist window?

Tags: vlc-media-player, ordering, playlists

In the VLC playlist window, I can't seem to drag the items around to change their order. Is that normal? In every other media player I've used before, this is possible.

At the moment I'm resorting to clicking the title to sort the list in an order which is what I want, but I can't guarantee I'll always have the titles so correct!

**UPDATE**

No one? I'd have though this would be a staple feature...

Comment: Have you tried the solutions offered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was apparently a [bug in version 1.0.2](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=65540) which has now been fixed in version 1.0.3. So you can either upgrade to 1.0.3 or revert to 1.0.1 or, if you really need to use 1.0.2, you could use this workaround:

1. go to **Media -> Save Playlist to File...** and save as a `.m3u` file
2. use your favorite text editor to reorder it to your heart's content
3. clear VLC's playlist and open your saved file

Answer (score 1):

VLC player is different than most media players' playlists in that you don't drag to the spaces in between other items but actually hover over the position you want it to go to (it will put a box around the item).

Answer (score 1):

I finally have an answer for this .. 
1) start by opening your playlist and playing any track
2) when it is playing .. drag the playing song up from the bottom of the screen - you should see your playlist with some icons at the top-right of the screen
3) hover your finger on any track name and drag it to a new position
4) carry on moving stuff until you are happy
5) select the three dots icon in the top right
6) select the save icon (looks like a black square disk with a hole in the middle)
7) Choose a name for your save list .. or tap on the the same name if you want to overwrite the original playlist name

Answer (score 0):

You may have the items arranged alphabetically or something. Check if the bar that says "Name" has an arrow on it, pointing up or down. if so, try clicking the empty bar in the top left of the playlist, beside "name"

Answer (score 0):

This is still broken, sometimes it works, sometimes i have to save my playlist, exit and restart vlc to reorder items, huge annoyance, but at least i can use vlc out of the box, unlike foobar2k. version 1.0.3 Goldeneye on Win 7 Pro x64 (msdn legit)

Answer (score 0):

VLC For Android
Open the playlist
Place finger on the = sign on left side of track and move the track up and down the playlist to reorder